# How can I use css selector to find elements after some element

Tags: html, css, selenium, css-selectors

I have this html code

```
.......
<div class="list-rows> </div>
<div class="list-rows> </div>

<div class="cat-row"><span>Topics</span></div>
<div class="list-rows> </div>
<div class="list-rows> </div>
<div class="list-rows> </div>
```

Now i want to find all div with class `list-rows` but which come after this element
`<div class="cat-row"><span>Topics</span></div>`

`div.cat-row +list-rows` is not working

Comment: arent you missing a quote after list-rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `~`:

```css
.cat-row ~ .list-rows {
    ...
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator

Answer (score 1):

Combining the comment and the two previous answers:

- Most of the `class=` attributes are missing their closing quotation marks.
- The CSS `list-rows` isn't preceded by a `.` to indicate that it *is* a class.
- The `+` (*next* younger sibling) in the CSS should be tilde`~` (*all* younger siblings).

Answer (score 0):

you need closing quotes on your class names in the html and you should use something like `div.cat-row+.list-rows` as a selector.